# Sim808 + Arduino UNO: Get Json Object Response from Web Server

Tags: html, json, arduino, at-command

How to read JSON object response from the server?

These are the commands I use:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPSSL=1
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.mywebsite.com/getTime?token=jsdaljdaskl"
AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1
AT+HTTPACTION=0
```

The returning request should be Json object, but the Sim808 read it as html response which gives error 606.

Comment: Write some code, and come back when you have issues with the code. Alternatively, visit https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ for advice. This site is for coding questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to define HTTP parameter content as JSON format using the following command

AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"

Found this document useful [HTTP Client using SIM900](http://www.electronicwings.com/avr-atmega/http-client-using-sim900a-gprs-and-atmega16).

Comment: I always get `HTTPACTION: 1,606,0` error on response. My web server is an MVC application. Why is this happening?